# Cannot remove handler whenever I leave activity, and they continue running when I come back

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I have the below handler :

```
  public static final int WORK = 2;
  public static final int UPDATE = 1;`

private Handler uiHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch (msg.what)
        {
        case UPDATE:
            // Perform UI updates here

            this.sendMessageDelayed(this.obtainMessage(WORK), 15000);

            break;

        case WORK:
        {           
            new Thread(doWork).start();
        }
            break;

        default:
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
};
```

This works super well.
However, the downside I am facing is the following.

Assume I run inside `onResume()` the following `uiHandler.sendMessageDelayed(uiHandler.obtainMessage(WORK), 500);`

Now the handler will run perfectly, lets say at time 9:00:10 , and will trigger to run the thread.

However, whenever I leave the activity, and go to another activity, then come back (rapidly) , another timer for the handler is starting.
Assume I came back from the other activity at 9:00:13

I will be having two threads running at both 9:00:15 and 9:00:28

And more if I go back and forth.

in my onPause I am calling `uiHandler.removeMessages(WORK);` but it is of no help.

Comment: If you want it to run once, why don't you put it on `onCreate`? Or if you want it to run `onResume` but only for certain cases, you could maybe use a flag.

Comment: @Chrys, I want it to run again whenever I return from onPause. `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);` < I used this and it seemed to do the trick. I did not test it heavily though. If anyone can confirm, I'll consider it as a solution.

Comment: Ah, I see. Does this stop any threads that have started too? If not, you could probably check and manually stop them on `onPause`.

Comment: uiHandler.removeMessages(WORK); is not supposed to work as it only removes the messages from message queue. If the message is executing, it won't do anything.

Comment: Why are you not using AsyncTask to do the thread work? It should work. In the postExecute method, you can stop the background work.